# How can I keep lines together between textarea Automatically in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I need a tool or a method letting me align two text areas based on a specific line in one textarea to the other.
in my case I have a headline in on texearea and need to align the rest normal text line with the first line in the second textarea as show in the attached file.
so how can I Keep lines text lines align together automatically?

[image: How to keep lines together]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your header into a separate text box. This way you will be able to align the other text boxes the way you like.

Example:

[image]